# Stack Overflow error in Merge Sort algorithm?

Tags: java, sorting, merge, mergesort, stack-overflow

I'm writing a merge sort class in java and i get a stack overflow error when I get to the `sort(left)` line. Any thoughts? I don't understand why this would be a problem.

package ds;

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MergeSorter<T> extends Sorter<T> {

public MergeSorter(Comparator<T> comparator){
    super(comparator);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void sort(T[] array){
    if (array.length <= 1);
    else {
        T[] left = (T[]) new Object[array.length/2 + 1];
        T[] right = (T[]) new Object[array.length/2 + 1];
        int middleIndex = array.length / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < middleIndex; i++) {
            left[i] = array[i];
        }
        for (int i = middleIndex; i < array.length; i++) {
            right[i - middleIndex] = array[i];
        }
        sort(left);
        sort (right);
        merge(left, right, array);
    }
}

public final void merge(T[] left, T[] right, T[] array){
    Array<T> sortedArray = new Array<T>(array.length);
    while (left.length > 0 || right.length > 0) {
        if (left.length > 0 && right.length > 0) {
            if (comparator.compare(left[0], right[0]) < 0) {
                sortedArray.add(left[0]);
                for (int i = 1; i < left.length; i++) {
                    left[i - 1] = left[i];
                    left[left.length - 1] = null;
                }
            }
            else {
                sortedArray.add(right[0]);
                for (int i = 1; i < right.length; i++) {
                    right[i - 1] = right[i];
                    right[right.length - 1] = null;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (left.length > 0) {
            sortedArray.add(left[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < left.length; i++) {
                left[i - 1] = left[i];
                left[left.length - 1] = null;
            }
        }
        else if (right.length > 0) {
            sortedArray.add(right[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < right.length; i++) {
                right[i - 1] = right[i];
                right[right.length - 1] = null;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = sortedArray.get(i);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the array has length `2`. Then left is:

```
T[] left = (T[]) new Object[array.length/2 + 1];
```

which is

```
T[] left = (T[]) new Object[2/2 + 1];
```

and this equals to

```
T[] left = (T[]) new Object[2];
```

And when you sort on `left`, this continues, and leads to an infinite recursion which might have caused the stack overflow error you posted.

Since you are copying the first `middleIndex` elements into `left`, `middleIndex` length should right fit the array `left`. So `left` should be a length `array.length/2` array.

Comment: Are you sure? Doesn't array.length count the number of elements in the array, not the actual capacity of the array? So even if the array is not full, array.length would still be good in the recursion, if i'm not mistaken. The reason I did this was to account for odd-sized arrays.

Comment: Array.length just return a fixed number, the array's length. I do not really get what you mean, but `[null, null]` has length 2.

Comment: You only want to add 1 to either the left or right. Integer division will round down then you need to decide where the 1 goes.